# .htaccess password protection with ip block

Tags: php, apache, web-services, security, webserver

I'm just trying to figure out the way trying to block user ip if they enter password 3 times wrong when prompted via .htaccess. I'm using this code to ask user user name and password. When they enter correct username password it allow user to view the webpage.Actually want to prevent brute force attack.

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "wp-admin"
AuthUserFile "/home/isportal/.htpasswds/public_html/wp-admin/passwd"
require valid-user
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check password 3 times wrong then follow the [tutorial](http://webcheatsheet.com/php/blocking_system_access.php). It is not possible by using .htaccess . You need php for this kind of task.

Block IP .htaccess Code:

```
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from 66.249.74.0/24
Allow from all
```

Comment: But even there is way for the .htaccess simply don't prompt again to the user to enter password when the enter password three time wrong. Right now user can enter wrong password as many times they can.i need page like unauthorized access after three try is that possible.

Comment: where you csn find the idea to make password 3 times wrong checker using htaccess. have you a link?

Comment: i got this idea in my mind to be honest i just search over the internet and cannot find the solution for that then i ask a question is that possible.

Comment: I have router when i enter into administration settings of router it ask for password when i enter three time wrong it will say unauthorized access and move me to some other page and i know that it asking the password on .htaccess method.